# Angular forms import issue

Tags: angular

I have following Angular app.component.ts file

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'blog';
}
```

I need import Forms Module in the app.component.ts, then how could I do this for following html file

```
<h1>What is Module in Angular</h1>
<form #simpleForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getValues(simpleForm.value)">
    <input type="text" ngModel name="user" placeholder="enter user name">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="age" placeholder="enter user age">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="address" placeholder="enter user address">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" ngModel name="password" placeholder="enter user password">
    <br><br>
    <button>Get User Values</button>
</form>
```

Comment: FormsModule has to be imported into your AppModule, not into your AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

- Forms module should be imported to your module(app.module.ts)
- If you want to use the reactive form you have to import "ReactiveFormsModule"
  [image: module.ts]
- If you are using the reactive form you have import Validators, FormGroup, FormControl
  [image]